# Is it possible to get commits history for one file in gitlab api?

Tags: api, gitlab

I want to get the commits or the last commit for one file in gitlab api like this:

`GET /projects/:id/repository/commits?path=fileName`

Gitlab support or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a patch that implements this feature:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18898

Unfortunately, it has not been merged yet:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/4814

*Edit: now merged, expected to land in 8.14.0 (2016-11-22): https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/146d4348ca6812e26729de40a831f4ae8c27fde6*

Answer (score 4):

Now you can do:

```
/projects/:id/repository/commits?path=:file_path
```

and receive array of commits about specific file.

[Link to documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits)

Comment: I was unsure regarding :file_path so I tested it, this worked for me:
`/projects/:id/repository/commits?path=README.md`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. With GitLab 7.14 you can only get all commits of a repository with the following command:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/commits
```

Comment: Right now not. You may want to analyze the API code and implement that feature :)